# Density based outlier detection of pixels in an image using python

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, dbscan, anomaly-detection

I have an image of resolution 256 x 256. My goal is to find the blurry white pixels which are outliers in an image. The images can be seen below and their required output is under them.
I applied DBSCAN clustering using sklearn with 1 as eps and 150 as min_samples. The result I got is amazing but it took 30 seconds and around 35 GB of my RAM. I want some other anomaly detection technique which can cluster the blurred white pixels from the rest of the blackish pixels. I tried to use Random forest and LOF but failed to get the desired result. The solution should be fast enough and use least RAM as possible. DBSCAN takes a long time and too much RAM. Clustering should be done without mentioning the number of clusters so that the algorithm can itself find the anomalous pixels.
The desired result that I need is below:
[image][image][image][image]

Comment: do you have any more examples ? if it's always about finding white/whitish pixels on a black background you would be better off using some simpler heuristic rather than an unsupervised ML algorithm. also DBScan may get rid of the need to specify the number of clusters but you still have to choose an eps and min_point value. The values you chose might work for that example on a single point but they may very well not for your other examples if they have more points: you'll end up having to decide what eps/minpoint value to chose instead of what number of clusters...

Comment: @user2969402 I have more examples with complicated shapes. After a lot of research, this eps and min_sample value work successfully for all the cases. Also always 2 clusters are formed if there is an anomaly. If the image is all blackish then only 1 cluster will be formed.  So, no need to change eps and min_samples. But DBSCAN takes a very long time and too much RAM. Is there any alternative way to apply DBSCAN using python so that it can analyze very fast and take least RAM ?

Comment: @user2969402 Also the background is not black completely. Though the pixel values in the blackish part are more similar. That is why I cannot use a simple heuristic approach. There is a need for an unsupervised technique that can cluster the background from the similar whitish pixels  That's why I used DBSCAN to cluster them according to density.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you should be using clustering here at all. You want to remove values with some threshold I guess. It's the wrong tool for this problem. If you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail - but this is not a nail.

Simplify your data to improve runtime. Most of the pixels are very clearly fine, so get rid of all the easy cases first. Which is exactly why I don't think your approach is appropriate, you waste a lot of CPU to compute something that you do not need.

Don't bother to try to make the clustering algorithm faster - insteadz reconsider your problem. What are you *really* trying to solve? Then design a method that does *exactly* and *directly* what you need, not via some half-suited proxy operation like clustering.

Comment: Well! clustering is needed here. I can definitely use a simplified approach with traditional computer vision. But as I said earlier the data is too varied and the light distribution is not uniform which will create a lot of false alarms. If I use a clustering approach then my false alarm rate is below 1%. The CPU usage will compromise in order to remove the false alarm. The blackish pixels in the background are not really black but are close to the white pixel values. A proper density-based clustering algorithm can find the dense whitish cluster part.

Comment: Well, since this is *not* clustering, but you just happened to find some hack involving DBSCAN that seems to work, I suggest you try to understand *what* makes it work, and then how to computer that directly without clustering.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I understand what you are pointing to. But I am really not able to figure out the reason how come DBSCAN is giving perfect results with no false alarm. Can you give me some solution or direction for the above example, please?

Comment: The perfection of DBSCAN is it gives only 1 cluster when all are blackish pixels, and give 1 cluster with outliers as -1 label if there are whitish pixels present.

Comment: Which indicates that some density theshold will do the trick. But as we don't have your data or preprocessing, we can't tell.

Comment: The data is above. I have posted one example above. I can post another image as well for example.

Comment: DBSCAN does not naturally handle pixel data. So there also is how you feed the data to the algorithm. And still I am quite certain that a trivial thresholding approach will work as good as this example. Select all point with a value larger than (max-min)/2, for example.

Comment: Yes definitely thresholding can work but when I use thresholding even after some blurring there are a lot of false alarm which is not suitable for users in production environment. Is there any way that I can optimize DBSCAN query so that it does not take 30 GB of RAM to query pixels of 256 × 256 resolution. My issue here is the RAM usage. Any other implementation of DBSCAN. I heard abt ELKI but I am not able to find a python implementation of it. I am kind of stuck.

Comment: Is there any possibility of using ELKI by Linux command line ? so that I can run it on jupyter

Comment: Yes, I use it mostly from C Makefiles, works perfectly. But again, I don't think that is the way to go. Solve your problem directly, not indirectly via clustering. Clustering will break eventually. So understand your problem better until you can **solve it without clustering**. Making clustering faster is a waste of time for you.